# Update price in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the "price" field in a product div.

I've managed to sort out the increments, so the price now changes.

However, It doesn't stay in it's format - it returns bad prices, such as:
£1.5 as opposed to £1.50
£0.39999999999999996 as opposed to £0.40, etc - I just want it to add the price of a product (£0.50) to the total price at the push of a button.

Here is my JavaScript so far:

```
function incrementquan'.$row["pid"].'(){
var input = document.getElementById("quan'.$row["pid"].'");
input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
var element = document.getElementById("price'.$row['pid'].'");
element.innerHTML = ("&pound;" + (input.value * '.$row['pprice'].'));
```

}

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you probably want to use `.toFixed()`.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript, how would I Implement `.toFixed()` with my current JavaScript?

Comment: With a quick google, I found out how: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: I'd prefer other sources, but yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed